# Expressing Notion of Type "Scale"

Tags: type-theory

I am looking for the terminology/concepts which express the nontechnical notion of the "layer" structuring of programs, the languages in which they are written, and a formal type theory.

For instance, we might have types defined for a single module, written in a language with a certain type system which may be a subset of a very abstract theory like system F, F-Omega, or CoC.

Is there a word or notion to express this "scale" of typing?

Comment: I guess conservative extensions of a set of base languages form a partial order. Given an expression and a type, the set of languages for which the expression has the given type may have an `inf` in this PO? I'm not sure what you are trying to do though.